# socket.io: how to ensure a value is set

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io

I have code that is relying on other code to be set before proceding.  How can I limit the dom to wait until stuff has been sent from the server before continuing?  I have tried a while statement, and I end up with "call stack exceeded" exception.  I have also tried setTimeOut, and while render() will function, I will still get an exception within render stating that selfId isn't defined yet.  How can I get around this stuff?

Example:
Client:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
        <link href="client/main.css" rel="stylesheet"</link>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="game">
            <!--GAMEBOARD-->
            <canvas id="ctx"></canvas>
            <!--CHATUI-->
            <div id="chat" class="chat">
                <div id="messages" class="messages">
                    <div>Welcome to Simon's Game Server</div>
                </div>
                <input id="chatinput" class="chatinput"></input>
            </div>
            <div id="fps"></div>
            <!--ADDITIONALUI-->
        </div>
        <script>
            var socket = io();
            //game loop
            var lastTime;
            function gameLoop() {

            }

            //init
            var selfId = null;   //How do i set this variable when the first user connects?  This is my question
            socket.on('setSelf', function (data) { //this is my attempt, but it is not working for the first user.
                console.log('Setting selfId to: ' + data.id);
                selfId = data.id;
                gameLoop();
            });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Server:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var port = 1338;
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

//routes
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/index.html');
});
app.use('/client', express.static(__dirname + '/client'));

server.listen(port);


var UNIQUEID = 0;
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.myid = UNIQUEID;
    UNIQUEID++;
    socket.emit('setSelf', { id: socket.myid }); 
});
```

Comment: why don't you call `gameLoop();` inside `setSelf`?

Comment: I tried this, and yet when I build the project and first hit the server and try echoing selfId on the console, it comes up as undefined.

Why???

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, you can't "Wait" or "Sleep" until something happens.  It doesn't work that way.  Instead, you register some sort of event handler and when that happens you trigger the code in question.  In your case, you can do that like this:

```
var selfId = null;
socket.on('setSelf', function (data) {
     selfId = data.id;
     // don't call gameLoop until you get here and selfId is set
     gameLoop();
});

function gameLoop() {
    render();
    //....
    playerState();
    //
    //etc ....
    //
}
```

---

Also, on the server, you should not be overwriting `socket.id` as socket.io coins its own id and uses that in its own housekeeping.  If you want to store something as a property on the `socket` object, I'd suggest you create your own unique, non-conflicting property name such as `.myId` instead.

Comment: Explain to me please why if I put console.log(selfId) just after selfId=data.id, the console on the client shows 0.   Yet, while I am on the client, if i type in the console selfId, I get Uncaught ReferenceError: selfId is not defined(…) ???

Comment: I tried this code, and still on a console if I try echoing selfId, I get that reference error.

Comment: @simon - You'll have to show me the exact code that causes that error because the code I have in my answer will not cause that.  My guess is that you did something different than what I show here.  Also, I notice that you're overwriting `socket.id`  on the server.  That's a very bad idea.  socket.io uses `socket.id` for it's own use.  If you want to store a property on the server-side socket object, create a different property name like `socket.myId` that does not conflict.

Comment: @simon - Probably `selfId` is inside some scope that the console can't reach, but your code that's in that same scope can reach it.  I'd have to see your whole code to know for sure.

Comment: I added complete picture of what I am doing for all convenience.  selfId is on the global <script> tag in the only html document I am serving to the client so far.

Comment: @simon - I can't see enough of the client code in that screen shot.  And, please don't use screen shots to communicate code - they are horrible for that.  In addition, your server code is repeating a lot of stuff that is built into the socket.io library for you.  It already coins a unique id for you in `socket.id`.  It already keeps a data structure of all open sockets in both `io.sockets.sockets` and `io.sockets.connected` (each is accessed differently - one is an array of sockets and the other is an object indexed by socket.id).

Comment: I do appreciate all the ideas you have given me @jfriend00.  I tried changing the property I was giving from socket.id to socket.myid, but still no luck.  All I want to do is have a global variable set on the client at initialization.  I need this so I can apply different rules later on in client code depending upon the state of the owner of that ID.

Comment: @simon - If you show me all of your client code, I can identify your issue for you.  But, I can't see enough in that screen shot.  What is wrong with the exact code in my question.  The variable `selfId` will be available in whatever scope the `var` definition was placed in and it will have a value as soon as the `setSelf` message is received.

Comment: Modified my original code to keep this simple.  There is my complete code, there is nothing else other than a css page.

Comment: @simon - OK, and what does `console.log('Setting selfId to: ' + data.id);` from where you have it show in the console?  Or, if you put `console.log(selfId)` into `gameLoop()`, what does it show?  I'm not sure I know exactly what the problem is?

Comment: When Chrome fires up, and I peak inside the console, I will see 0.  But inside the console, if I try performing the exact same command, console.log(selfId), it states that it is undefined.  See my first two comments.

Comment: Why are you spending so much energy on what the console tells you?  What matters is what your code says.  Put a `console.log(selfId)` into your code in a meaningful place and see what that says.  I don't know what exactly you're doing in the console or the timing of when you're doing it, but it's kind of irrelevant.  What matters is what your code can access and you're better off testing that with either a `console.log()` statement in your code or inspecting variables from a breakpoint.  Both of those techniques have a known scope and known timing.

Comment: I just stated what I am performing in the console.  I am being as clear as I can.  Try the above code, run it, and on the client open the console, and ask for the console to output the contents of selfId.  It does not exist, and this is a problem for me.

Comment: To reiterate the importance:  This isn't my full code (obviously), but what I plan on doing with the client side code is creating instances of a player class, and that class is dependent upon an ID.  If that ID happens to be undefined, when I perform new Player(selfId), all hell breaks loose.  This is why it is important to me, and not to just the console.

Comment: @simon - I'm done.  If you declare `var selfId` at the top level as a global, then it will  contain a valid value anytime you access it AFTER you initialize it.  There's really nothing else to say here.  If it isn't getting initialized, then debug why that is.  If you're accessing it BEFORE you initialize it, then fix that (that's what my answer is mostly about).  There is nothing else to say.

Comment: @simon - So don't do `new Player(selfId)` until AFTER the value of `selfId` is initialized. That's the ENTIRE key here and that's what my answer is about.  Don't run your other initialization code until you receive that `setSelf` message.  Then, call your initialization code from that message handler after you've initialized `selfId` to have the desired value.

Comment: How do I wait for it to get initialized?

The above code doesn't initialize it.  When I try new Player(selfId), I get the same thing.
How can I ensure that that it is initialized differently than what I have posted above?

Comment: @simon - My goodness.  See where my answer calls `gameLoop()`.  That's when you first know that `selfId` has a value and that's where you call your initialization code to start things off.  That's the ONLY way to do it.  It's as if you've ignored everything that's in my answer or my comments.  Something in my writing is just not getting through.  Javascript is an event-driven language.  You call code from events.  You have an event that indicates `selfId` is now valid.  So, call your startup code from there.  I'm going to sleep now.